# strange comparison error in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

Following is the part of my template that is having problem.

```
<select id="country" name="country_id">
        {% for country in countries%}
        {{country.id}} {{country_id}}
         {% if country.id==country_id %}
        <option value="{{ country.id }}"  selected="selected"  >
        {%else%}
        <option value="{{ country.id }}" >
         {%endif%}
            {{ country.name }}
        </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

It gives error on this line:  `{% if country.id==country_id %}`. Following is the error shown:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '==country_id' from 'country.id==country_id'
```

For me it is very strange that it is giving error on simple comparison statement. I also tried `ifequal` statement but that also didn't serve the purpose. What is the cause of this this problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need spaces around the `==`, i.e.:

```
{% if country.id == country_id %}
```

Comment: by sepearating with space it doesn't give error but still never enter in if block while both country_id and country.id have same value that is 2.

Comment: one 2 is coming from db while other from query string, so can there be data type difference?

Comment: ok it worked Chris, problem was of type difference, so I just did explicity type casting and it worked. :)